# ¿Por qué las etiquetas [vscode] y [visual-studio-code] no son sinónimos?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Navegando hoy, me di cuenta que las etiquetas [vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) y [visual-studio-code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) NO son sinónimos, lo cual no pasa en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) (el sitio en inglés), pues son sinónimos

Lo que propongo es crear un sinónimo de etiquetas entre [vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) y [visual-studio-code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code), si es posible.

---

Editado por gbianchi:

Hay 150 preguntas con el [visual-studio-code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)
Hay 215 preguntas con el [vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode)

Comment: me parece perfecto.. hagamos un par de respuestas para ver con cual nos deberiamos quedar...ç

Answer (score 20, accepted):

todas las nuevas [visual-studio-code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) deberian ser renombradas a [vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode)

Comment: Excelente @gbianchi, me parece mejor esta opción, pues la etiqueta sería más corta, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Cuando busco algo sobre el editor siempre escribo vscode

Comment: Entonces, se completo?

Comment: @JuanRivera si!

Comment: También debería gestionarse [tag:visual-studio] y [tag:vs], así como mapear [tag:vs2017] y [tag:vsts] a sus homólogas `[visual-studio-X]`.

Comment: visual studio y vs estaria bien.. yo eliminaria vs.. ojo que por ejemplo en vs2019 podes hacer cosas que en vs2017 no... y vsts es otra cosa....

Comment: Ay que me contestaste, usa `@fed...` que otra gente habló. Bueno me refiero a juntar [tag:visual-studio-ts] con [tag:vsts]. Y lo mismo con [tag:visual-studio-2017] con [tag:vs2017].

Comment: ah si si... en esas estoy de acuerdo! despues cuando pueda hago un rastreo... @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Answer (score -5):

todas las nuevas [vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) deberian ser renombradas a [visual-studio-code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)